# how to avoid multithreading in JSP?

Tags: multithreading, jsp

I have been using `jsp` and `servlets` for quite long time. I never come across multithreading and its concepts. I just want to know to avoid multithreading on java servlet page.

Comment: No you don't, you want to know how to let it happen correctly. The answer is to avoid instance variables and static variables. A single-threaded web application would be completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

> i just want to know to avoid multithreading on java servlet page

unless you're using local variables all the time  or  all your instance variables are `final`, you can't escape multithreading. Your `HttpSession` , `ServletContext` attributes , non-final  instance and static members are all vulnerable to multithreading issues.